# Why does DropDownPreference require a delay before the value can be selected?

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx

I'm trying to programmatically populate a `DropDownPreference` from `androidx.preference` and then select one the elements.

With this version, the selected value does not change.

```
    runOnUiThread {
        dropdownPreference.entries = newEntries
        dropdownPreference.entryValues = newValues
        dropdownPreference.value = initialValue // doesn't work
    }
```

If I introduce a delay, it DOES work.

```
    runOnUiThread {
        dropdownPreference.entries = newEntries
        dropdownPreference.entryValues = newValues

        Thread{
            Thread.sleep(200) // Doesn't work without this delay.
            runOnUiThread { dropdownPreference.value = initialValue }
        }.start()
    }
```

I'm not entirely sure what's going, and this feels like a terrible solution.

My assumption is that it takes time for `DropDownPreference` to update itself, and that work is not done on the UI thread. So setting the selection immediately doesn't work. But I can't find any listener for detecting when the update is complete.

Comment: Preferences in the preferences library all work exclusively synchronously on the main thread. Why are you inducing a delay with `runOnUiThread` in the first place? Where is your code being called from? And do you mean the value of the backing SharedPreference doesn't change, or that the UI doesn't change to reflect the new value?

Comment: The UI doesn't get updated. The preference isn't even changing, this is all just to get DropDownPreference populated in the first place.

This code is getting called from a worker thread because getting the list entries takes a few seconds of network i/o.

Comment: Are you sure newEntries and newValues aren’t still empty when this code is called? Maybe you call those before the IO work is done?